# Syntax to add multiple commands to a single command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am looking to try and set multiple commands in a single command block, but so far everything I have tried just returns "Unknown Command".

What is the format for writing multiple commands in a single command block in Minecraft 1.8?

Can I use either of the following:

```
Command:(command here) Command:(command here)
```

```
/command here; /command here;
```

Or is there another format?

Comment: There are 1.14 updated versions here: https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2980388-1-14-multiple-commands-in-one-command-block I could not post the content as an answer because reputation

Comment: @deb0ch interesting find! However, I'm not sure if this is multiple commands in one command block; this looks like it might be summoning multiple command blocks at once?

Comment: It might also be along the same lines as what [Sky's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/213082/73976) has suggested?

Comment: Sky is using `FallingSand`, which as I understand it is the old, deprecated version of `falling_block`, so his command won't work in 1.14. I have been testing it for a bit and I can guarantee that all the commands in the command block minecarts are effectively run in Minecraft 1.14, and as far as my research showed, this hack it is the only way to run multiple commands from one command block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer for the format is:

`N/A`

Currently there is no way to set two commands in one single command block (after using the powerful Google). I don't know why, but you just can't.

If you want to set up multiple commands, use redstone wire to link them up. That's the most simple way.

Comment: Is that since 1.8? Because I've seen it done in older versions...

Comment: It has never been done, @Ben. It has never been in the game.

Comment: It is possible to run multiple command with 1 command using stacked command block minecarts, though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVGJsleC6Wc

Comment: @QbsidianH20 That's still only running one command per command block, may be suitable to OP's needs though.

Comment: ugh.  i'm trying to build using /fill and i have to press two buttons, select all from streaming and paste then hit enter for *every* command.  And for a single excavation it takes NINE commands, so i was *really* hoping to automate it a bit more!

Comment: As of 1.9, chain command blocks can be used instead of redstone wire

Answer (score 8):

You cant write multiple commands in one command block but you can use one command to spawn more command blocks.
If you mess around with the Riding datatag you can get fallingsand entities with commands in them to ride on top of each other.
For example:

```
/summon Falling sand ~ ~2 ~ {Time:1,TileID:137,TileEntityData:{Command:/say hi},Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,TileID:137,TileEntityData:{Command:/say hello}}
```

Now if you want them to activate simultaneously you could do something like

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~ ~0 ~1 ~ ~-4 ~1 redstone_block"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:setblock ~ ~3 ~1 stone},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:setblock ~ ~4 ~ command_block 0 replace {Command:fill ~ ~2 ~ ~ ~-8 ~1 air}},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"/say Hello"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"/say Hi"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:stone,Time:1}}}}}}}
```

This is the only way to get multiple commands in one command block, if you know how FallingSand works this would make a lot more sense, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

An easy format I have come up with to do this without any external program with the falling sand method is to start with this command

```
summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Time:1,Block:redstone_block,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:____},Riding:{}}}
```

and insert your first command into "{Command:____}", replacing the ____, and then copy this:

```
id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:redstone_block,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:____},Riding:{}}
```

into the brackets at the rightmost "Riding{}" and enter the next command into the next "{Command:____}". Once you have entered in all your commands, you need to delete the last Riding{}, or the command won't run. Keep in mind that the commands will execute in the reverse order than what you input them in.

If you want to delete the extra block spawned or even the original command block itself as well, then start with this command

```
summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Time:1,Block:redstone_block,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:/fill ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~-? ~ air},Riding{}}
```

and replace the question mark at "~ ~-? ~" with 2 * the amount of commands you used and add to that 2 if you want to leave the original command block or 3 if you only want to run it once and then delete it.