# How do you summon 100 zombies with one command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minigame and I need to summon 100 Zombies in 1 command block. How do I do so?

Comment: Use a [function](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Function).  Here is a question that may help: [Problem with multiple commands in one Command Block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/318607/186522).  Here is another: [Syntax to add multiple commands to a single command block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/194995/186522)

Comment: In your case, you could just put a button on a repeatimg command block.

Answer (score 3):

To summon multiple entities in one command, summon them riding an AEC that will die in the next tick:

```
/summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:zombie"},{id:"minecraft:zombie"},{id:"minecraft:zombie"},{id:"minecraft:zombie"},{id:"minecraft:zombie"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was extremely helpful to my son and me.